# ASP.NET Roles and Permissions

Tags: asp.net, authentication, permissions, authorization

I'm using the ASP.NET/C# Login control and that entire authentication and authorization system.

I set up the roles and have users go to certain pages when they log into the system dependent on their role. Right now I'm trying to restrict access to certain pages, which is working correctly. However, when it restricts the access to a user who shouldn't be allowed in that web page it redirects to login.aspx. I don't have a login page, I just have a login user control that sits on a master page.

How can I get it to redirect to a different page on permission failure rather than go to login.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

set the login page in web.config